# How to avoid random fill pattern dialog box when using action in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I want to create an action that fills pattern randomly. I have created a sample pattern but it show me dialog box for random pattern setting every time when I play action. How to avoid that dialog box and set random pattern automatically.

Here is screenshot of dialog that what I'm talking about [image]

Here is the sample action that I have created [Download from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zkrwwykrtl8h3z/Sample.zip?dl=0).

Sample output what I'm expecting. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the dialogue box toggled off.

[image]

Comment: yes it is off. you can check it in sample action that i have upload.

Comment: @AmitBamrotiya Your Sample action runs fine with no dialogues for me. Have you tried closing out Photoshop and reopening it?

Comment: have you got result with random fill pattern?

Comment: @AmitBamrotiya  Your sample action contains no pattern fill.

Comment: i have created pattern with setting of random pattern, but it take last used setting of path fill option like if i use fill with color in other file then output is with fill color. is there any way to record random fill pattern?

Comment: above image with fill black dots is created with that sample action.